# Adding reccuring events in google calendar with time

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I need to add recurring events with start time and end time. I used the code like

```
$recurrence = "DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:{$start}\r\n" .
            "DTEND;VALUE=DATE:{$start2}\r\n" .
            "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY={$dtString};UNTIL={$end}\r\n";
```

Where `$start = '20120601', $end = '20120630', $dtString = 'Fr'`

i need to add events which start from 08:00 to 09:00 which repeat every Friday. Please help me to find-out a solution

Regards,
NisanthKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send you a page to help you.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents

Mauricio.

Comment: If I have infinite recurrence then how can I sync this data with google calendar ???